# Detect single-byte character set from the command-line?

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, charset

I have a bunch of text files in a directory. They have text in, say, English and Arabic - or both. The English-only ones only use characters from the windows-1252 codepage (or ISO-8859-1 / Latin-1 if you like), while the Arabic ones use windows-1256 (or iso-8859-6 if you like).

My question: Can I, from the (Unix'ish) command-line, detect which file uses which codepage, with decent reliability?

Note: `file -i` doesn't do it...

Comment: By definition, this is somewhat impossible, be it on the command line or elsewhere. You need specialised tools that use language-specific heuristics to guess whether some piece of text may make sense in it or not. So this basically is a request for tools…

Comment: @deceze: You've replaced a "no" answer with a closure. I absolutely did not request some speciality tool. This is one of innumerable questions regarding how to do something in a typical Unix'ish command-line environment.

Comment: @einpoklum It's impossible to do without specialized tool, because file with text in windows-1252 doesn't have info about its codepage, so as file with text in windows-1256. Although, you can search for bytes `0x81`, `0x8D` and `0x8F`, and if the file has it, that's _probably_ windows-1256, because in windows-1252 these bytes aren't used.

Comment: @Styx: Thanks. Too bad you can't make that an answer.